# Multiplying a string with a float

Tags: python, floating-point, sequence, multiplication

So, I am very new to python but have done a little bit of programming in matlab. So now i have two values that i want to multply by the same constant, for example:

`res = 1920, 1080`

`win_scale = 1/1.25`

`width, height = res*win_scale`

which gives me the error:
"can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

I have found other related questions but none that I can understand. Thank you

Comment: If you explained what outcome you wanted, someone might be able to hep explain how to get it using Python.

Comment: Use: `width, height = [x*win_scale for x in res]`, or maybe better/more explicit `width = res[0]*win_scale ; height = res[1]*win_scale`

Comment: I just want a sequence saying:
`width, height = 1920/1.25, 1080/1.25`
or rather:
`width, height = 1536, 864`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want each value in `res` multiplied by the float:

```
width, height = [x * win_scale for x in res]
```

Comment: I dont really understand what this is saying but yes this is what i wanted, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply a list by a float. You have to do it with an int. And I don't believe it will output what you want.

```
a = [1920, 1080]
# Doing a * 2 will output you [1920, 1080, 1920, 1080]
```

What you are looking for I think is element-wise multiplication which you can do with list like this

```
a = [i * 2 for i in a]
```

But the best option would be to use a Numpy array by importing the library. Numpy array supported this type of element wise operation and you can do in fact

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([1920, 180])
a * 2 # This will give you a = [3840, 2160]
```

Comment: ok i think it is time to get numpy then...

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to convert `res` to a `numpy` array. That would allow you to multiply a number with the array's items in just a single line without the need of an loops.

Just do this.

```
import numpy as np

width, height = np.array(res) * win_scale
print(width, height)
```

Output -

```
(1536.0, 864.0)
```